# How do I load an index (Dow, Nasdaq) with Zipline?

Tags: python, zipline

Loading individual stocks is no problem but I was struggeling with loading stock indexes for a while so I thought I should share.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load an index with zipline just add it to the stock parameter like this:

```
    data = load_from_yahoo(stocks=['AAPL', '^gspc', '^ixic'], indexes={}, start=datetime(2014, 1, 1), end=datetime(2015,4,2))
```

This will load both Apple's stock prices, NASDAQ Composite and s&p500.

Comment: For reference, if you [click on NASDAQ on Yahoo finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=^ixic), you'll get an URL parameter `s=^ixic`. Apply that to all indices you need.